# display KML layers from check box selection - problems drawing layers in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to have multiple KML layers (all stored within the same Fusion table) display on a google map based on user selection through check boxes. The map and the check boxes have been appearing, but the KML layers have not (usually I get a tiled "Data may still be loading" response across the map window).  I've based the coding off of a google fusion table example (IN:pizza shops).

I'm pretty new to html & java, so even though I've been unable to find any errors in my script, or any glaring differences from other 'help' pages like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855067/toggle-kml-layers-in-google-maps-v3) doesn't mean there aren't errors somewhere.

I've written a bunch of these for each of the layer types:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementBId('trail'),
        'click', function() {
            filterMap(layer, tableId, map);
    });
```

And then this to try to get the map filtered:

```
        function filterMap(layer, tableId, map) {
        var where = generateWhere();

        if (where) {
            if (!layer.getMap() ) {
                layer.setMap(map);
            }
            layer.setOptions({
                query: {
                    select: 'geometry',
                    from: tableId,
                    where: where
                }
            });
        } else {
            layer.setMap(null);
        }
    }

    function generateWhere() {
        var filter = [];
        var stores = document.getElementsByName('store');
        for (var i = 0, store; store = stores[i]; i++) {
            if (store.checked) {
                var storeName = store.value.replace(/'/g, '\\\'');
                filter.push("'" + storeName + "'");
            }
        }
        var where = '';
        if (filter.length) {
            where =  "'descripion' IN (" + filter.join(',') + ')';
        }
        return where;
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

And then these guys in the div body:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="store"
            id="trail" value="trail">
        <label>trail</label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="store"
            id="Historic" value="Historic">
        <label>Historic</label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="store"
            id="Energy" value="Energy">
        <label>Energy</label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="store"
            id="Hunting/Fishing" value="Hunting/Fishing">
        <label>Hunting/Fishing</label>
```

My Fusion table is: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1J8YjRYnWprhLdL0YMP6lxxb_encjkowSlqi1G3Y#rows:id=1

Answer (score 0):

there is a typo:

```
    where =  "'description' IN (" + filter.join(',') + ')';
    //----------------^
```

The **t** is missing in your code.