# Google Maps API creating legend for toggling KML layers on/off

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In the code below, I'm attempting to [create a legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167895/interactive-legend-in-google-maps-api-v3-with-two-or-more-kml-layers) over my map so that I can allow the user to turn individual KML layers on/off via checkbox.

The updated code is below that is now working thanks to @geocodezip

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>KML Layers</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API-KEY-HERE]">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="toggle_box"></div>

<script>
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {
      lat: 41.876,
      lng: -87.624
    }
  });

  createTogglers(kml);
  removeAll(kml);
  startup();

} //End initMap
var kml = {
  fubo: {
    name: "Fubo TV",
    url: 'http://streambuzz.net/wp-content/uploads/fubo.kml'
  },
  vue: {
    name: "Playstation Vue",
    url: 'http://streambuzz.net/wp-content/uploads/psvue.kml'
  },
  hulu: {
    name: "Hulu",
    url: 'http://streambuzz.net/wp-content/uploads/hulu.kml'
  },
  dtvnow: {
    name: "DIRECTV NOW",
    url: 'http://streambuzz.net/wp-content/uploads/dtvnow.kml'
  },
  yttv: {
    name: "YoutTube TV",
    url: 'http://streambuzz.net/wp-content/uploads/yttv.kml'
  }
}
// the important function... kml[id].xxxxx refers back to the top
function toggleKML(checked, id) {
  if (checked) {
    var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kml[id].url, {
      preserveViewport: true,
      suppressInfoWindows: true
    });
    //store kml as obj
    kml[id].obj = layer;
    kml[id].obj.setMap(map);
  } else {
    kml[id].obj.setMap(null);
    delete kml[id].obj;
  }
}

// create the controls dynamically because it's easier, really
function createTogglers(kml) {
  var html = "<form><ul>";
  for (var prop in kml) {
    //console.log(prop);
    html += "<li id=\"selector-" + prop + "\"><input type='checkbox' id='" + prop + "'" +
      " onclick='highlight(this,\"selector-" + prop + "\"); toggleKML(this.checked, this.id)' \/>" +
      kml[prop].name + "<\/li>";
  }

  html += "<li class='control'><a href='#' onclick='removeAll(kml);return false;'>" + "Remove all layers<\/a><\/li>" + "<\/ul><\/form>";
  document.getElementById("toggle_box").innerHTML = html;
}

// easy way to remove all objects
function removeAll(kml) {
  for (var prop in kml) {
    if (kml[prop].obj) {
      kml[prop].obj.setMap(null);
      delete kml[prop].obj;
    }
  }
}


// Append Class on Select
function highlight(box, listitem) {
  var selected = 'selected';
  var normal = 'normal';
  document.getElementById(listitem).className = (box.checked ? selected : normal);
}

function startup() {
  // for example, this toggles kml hulu on load and updates the menu selector
  var checkit = document.getElementById('hulu');
  checkit.checked = true;
  toggleKML(checkit, 'hulu');
  highlight(checkit, 'selector-hulu');
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It will work the same regardless of using KML or KMZ files? (as long as they meet the restrictions)

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm just getting started with the Maps API. My "My Maps" version has everything I need except OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier support. Which is why I'm moving to the API version. However, the layers toggle built into "My Maps" is perfect - trying to recreate that.

Comment: I get an error with the posted code: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of null`, on this: `var checkit = document.getElementById('hulu');
          checkit.checked = true;` (there is no element with id "hulu" when that code runs)

Comment: The createTogglers() function should be creating that element on the fly (if I understand the original solution I linked to correctly).

Comment: Never the less, that element doesn't exist when the code is trying to access it (it is never created by `createTogglers`, that function takes an argument which you aren't providing).  The major problem with the posted code is the URLs are being loaded unconditionally (in initMap).  Then the URLs used by the "toggled" layers are different/wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element with id="hulu" doesn't exist when the code is trying to access it. It is never created by `createTogglers`, that function takes an argument which the call isn't providing.

```
createTogglers(kml);
removeAll(kml);
startup();
```

The URLs in KmlLayers populated in the `initMap` function are different from those in the `kml` object.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/6vLh4fck/9/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {
      lat: 41.876,
      lng: -87.624
    }
  });

  createTogglers(kml);
  removeAll(kml);
  startup();

} //End initMap
var kml = {
  fubo: {
    name: "Fubo TV",
    url: 'http://streambuzz.net/wp-content/uploads/fubo.kml'
  },
  vue: {
    name: "Playstation Vue",
    url: 'http://streambuzz.net/wp-content/uploads/psvue.kml'
  },
  hulu: {
    name: "Hulu",
    url: 'http://streambuzz.net/wp-content/uploads/hulu.kml'
  },
  dtvnow: {
    name: "DIRECTV NOW",
    url: 'http://streambuzz.net/wp-content/uploads/dtvnow.kml'
  },
  yttv: {
    name: "YoutTube TV",
    url: 'http://streambuzz.net/wp-content/uploads/yttv.kml'
  }
}
// the important function... kml[id].xxxxx refers back to the top
function toggleKML(checked, id) {
  if (checked) {
    var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kml[id].url, {
      preserveViewport: true,
      suppressInfoWindows: true
    });
    //store kml as obj
    kml[id].obj = layer;
    kml[id].obj.setMap(map);
  } else {
    kml[id].obj.setMap(null);
    delete kml[id].obj;
  }
}

// create the controls dynamically because it's easier, really
function createTogglers(kml) {
  var html = "<form><ul>";
  for (var prop in kml) {
    //console.log(prop);
    html += "<li id=\"selector-" + prop + "\"><input type='checkbox' id='" + prop + "'" +
      " onclick='highlight(this,\"selector-" + prop + "\"); toggleKML(this.checked, this.id)' \/>" +
      kml[prop].name + "<\/li>";
  }

  html += "<li class='control'><a href='#' onclick='removeAll(kml);return false;'>" + "Remove all layers<\/a><\/li>" + "<\/ul><\/form>";
  document.getElementById("toggle_box").innerHTML = html;
}

// easy way to remove all objects
function removeAll(kml) {
  for (var prop in kml) {
    if (kml[prop].obj) {
      kml[prop].obj.setMap(null);
      delete kml[prop].obj;
    }
  }
}


// Append Class on Select
function highlight(box, listitem) {
  var selected = 'selected';
  var normal = 'normal';
  document.getElementById(listitem).className = (box.checked ? selected : normal);
}

function startup() {
  // for example, this toggles kml hulu on load and updates the menu selector
  var checkit = document.getElementById('hulu');
  checkit.checked = true;
  toggleKML(checkit, 'hulu');
  highlight(checkit, 'selector-hulu');
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="toggle_box"></div>
```

Comment: +1 I've updated my code with your example and included the bits I had to change. Which was just the API encoded script source which I had to modify to remove the async defer and the callback handler from the URL. Its working perfectly now. Thanks!

Comment: The asynchronous defer isn't required.